# varying URL params in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

Been looking for awhile for an answer to this question, so beginning to wonder if it's possible.

I'm building a routeProvider config in my Angular app, that relies on both location names and a year parameter to aggregate data. Ideally (though don't know if possible) I'd like be able to have the following possible url structures:

```
'example.com/:country'
'example.com/:country/:year'
'example.com/:country/:state/'
'example.com/:country/:state/:year'
'example.com/:country/:state/:city'
'example.com/:country/:state/:city/:year'
```

So that a user could hit urls like so: `'example.com/usa'` or `'example.com/usa/2012'` (if they don't provide a year, it would just grab the most recent years data) 
Obviously I run into problems here though because when you visit 
 `'example.com/:country/:state/'`, the route provider is expecting state to be a year parameter.

My question is there anyway to allow this kind of structure? i'm not really sure where to start in adding the logic to allow both, or if it's possible, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

****Edit** I've read a little about ui.router and state params, though admittedly know little about it, but wondering if that might work somehow?

Comment: I'm starting to learn routing as well.  It doesn't seem that dynamic, as you indicate.  It seems awfully hacked, but I guess you could just parse the full URL in a controller to get the desired effect.  Really not the right approach, but at least from what I can tell, Angular just pays attention to the first parameter, as your post suggests.

Comment: In checking out ui-router more, I've found a somewhat hacky way I could possibly do it, in that ui-router supports regex patterns for params. So I could check if the parameter is numbers only or characters only..though that feels hacky

Comment: It might make more sense to use query parameters in this instance instead of routes past :country, since the order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principles of REST suggest that your URLs should be describing the **resource(s)** you wish to retrieve.

That seems clear enough however, to my mind at least, that still implies two valid approaches.

**HTTP Query**

The first is to create a URL that defines a `query`, an HTTP search for the *type* resource you want, and then to specify the actual resource you want via *refinement parameters* (the much abused `query string`). In this case you are not using a REST URL as such but rather you are *searching* for a country via the intrinsic HTTP search mechanism.

This is a perfectly valid approach that enjoys the benefit of HTTP upstream caching. The query string is only a `bad thing` when you use it to trigger logic, in other words when you use it to specify actions, verbs rather than a nouns (aka RPC).

```
The Query
'example.com/country'

The Refinement Parameters
 - year or  
 - city or  
 - state
```

**REST URLs**

The second, REST oriented approach, requires that each distinct `country+city+state+year` combination has its own equally distinct URL.

This is what you are trying to achieve, I believe, but you are failing because you are trying to be too succinct. There is not enough URL structure to uniquely distinguish each possible resource.

To solve this you just need too add more URL structure - like so:

```
//Syntax for ui.router
'example.com/country/{country}'
'example.com/country/{country}/year/{year}'
'example.com/country/state/{state}'
'example.com/country/state/{state}/year/{year}'
'example.com/country/state/{state}/city/{city}'
'example.com/country/state/{state}/city/{city}/year/{year}'
```

You can hook all those routes up to the same controller and put logic there, or divide them up between various controllers happy that the data they receive must be present.

This is typically the approach I use and whilst at first it feels as though the URLs are multiplying and that they are long and cumbersome, coal-face application of the technique turns out to be just fine and the URLs are clear, easy to machine generate if required, and self-documenting.

A final point, if you are using `ui.router` with `AngularJS`, it is often the case that you can prettify the *public facing* URLs, those the user will see. After all with an SPA they are not actually 'going' anywhere but rather specifying the internal state of the client browser so you can get clever with what they mean to you. The majority of the URLs you will be using will be hidden API calls and they can and should be as expressive as possible even if they are long and appear at first sight to be cumbersome.

In short, for API calls, clarity over succinctness is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected, but your explanation helps me wrap my head around it a little more

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using query strings in your route? eg:

`example.com/:country?year=2013&state=NY`

This way they are optional, and ordering is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I had I orginally thought but wanted to see if someone had any other ideas.